# data transformation (gather?)

Tags: r

I have the following tibble:

```
~id, ~a, ~b, ~c, ~d,
1, 10, 20, 33, 42,
2, 30, 20, 32, 42,
3, 34, 24, 35, 32,
4, 32, 24, 35, 25,
5, 22, 14, 35, 36,
...
)
```

But I'd rather like to have it in that form (only columns 'a' and 'b')

```
~id, ~aOrB, ~value
1, a, 10,
1, b, 20,
2, a, 30,
2, b, 20,
3, a, 34,
3, b, 24,
...
```

Does anyone know how to get it? I think it can be done using "gather()", but I didnt manage to get it working:

```
newTable <- oldTable %>% gather(a, b, value='cases')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `?gather` to read more on how to use the `gather` function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

oldTable %>% select(-c, -d) %>% gather(key = aOrB, value = value, -id)
```

EDIT: If you want to keep `c` and `d`, but not stacked:

```
    oldTable %>% gather(key = aOrB, value = value, -id, -c, -d)
```

If you want to keep `c` and `d`, and stacked along with `a` and `b`:

```
    oldTable %>% gather(key = aOrBOrCOrd, value = value, -id)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works well. But is there I possibility to keep the other columns c and d in the new tibble as well - without transforming them?

Comment: Edited my response.